# React Native Redux - Assigning a state property from prepopulated data

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm new to Redux and React Native so my apologies if I'm making an obvious mistake.

Here's a bit of background before I get to the error I'm encountering.

I have a state and a database(SQLite).  I have an instance in which I need to wipe the state and repopulate the state from the database.  I've already gathered and parsed the data from the database and just need to add it into the state.

Specifics: I have a list of objects (we'll say cars) in the database, each with their own properties.  I created a list of cars and passed that.  Once received, I create a "fake state" (which is just the empty initial state) and mutated that by adding in the list of cars since I know you shouldn't mutate the actual state.

I then try to return the state with the new cars property.

I get an error stating: TypeError: One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. Are you trying to assign a prototype property? We don't allow it, as this is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.

Am I understanding this to say that I cannot assign a redux state property like I'm trying to?

```
const initialState = {
  cars: [],
  selectedDevice: null,
};

const getNewCarList = async (previousState) => {
  const carList = await DBProvider.callQueryDB();

  const carListLength = carList.length;
  let newState = previousState;

  for (let i = 0; i < carListLength; i += 1) {
    newState = {
      ...newState,
      cars: newState.car.concat({
        carName: carList[i].carName,
        carID: carList[i].carID,
      }),
    };
  }
  return newState;
};


const refreshStore = async (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REFRESH_STORE: {
      const newCarState = await getNewCarList(initialState).then(newState => newState);

      return {
        ...state,
        car: newCarState.cars,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for that error message turns up [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663466/got-one-of-the-sources-for-assign-has-an-enumerable-key-on-the-prototype-chain), which links to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16814 .   It appears that this is a React Native specific issue of sorts that is a combination of your API call and the use of the spread operator.

Beyond that, your code has a couple major problems:

- You're making async calls in a reducer, which you should never do
- the handling of the list from the API response can be simplified

I'd suggest reworking your logic along these lines:

```
// Handle the request in a thunk function
function getNewCarList() {
     return async (dispatch) => {
         const carList = await DBProvider.callQueryDB();

         // dispatch an action containing the cars array
         dispatch({
             type : "REFRESH_STORE",
             payload : {
                 cars : carList
             }
         });
     }
}

function carsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "REFRESH_STORE" : {
            // the reducer just returns a new state value with the new array
            return {
                ...state,
                cars : action.payload.cars
            }
        }
        default : return state;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm trying your way but I'm getting an error saying that actions must be plain objects and custom middleware must be used for async actions.  Is that what thunk is for?

Comment: Yes, that assumes you have the `redux-thunk` middleware already configured.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with a slightly modified version of your code (to fit my situation of course).